# check condition doesn't work and returning unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiimageview, subview

The "if" condition works at the first loop but it doesn't work at the second loop
i dont understand why it doesn't want to check my condition at the second loop and why does it only work at the first loop

```
for (UIView *view in dro.subviews) {
    for (TOJDropableButtonView *v in view.subviews) {
        if ([v.type isEqualToString:targetView.filterItem.searchFilterItem.type]){
            NSLog(@"%@", targetView.filterItem.searchFilterItem.type);
        }
    }
}


-[UIImageView type]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x161bb960
2012-12-11 20:18:00.985 HungryNow[2507:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView type]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x161bb960'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1790012 0x149de7e 0x181b4bd 0x177fbbc 0x177f94e 0x1f401 0x2fe45 0x2ec6c 0x14b1705 0x4f2f4c 0x4f2fbc 0x41833f 0x418552 0x3f63aa 0x3e7cf8 0x27f2df9 0x27f2ad0 0x1705bf5 0x1705962 0x1736bb6 0x1735f44 0x1735e1b 0x27f17e3 0x27f1668 0x3e565c 0x24ad 0x23d5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are casting all your subviews to TOJDropableButtonView.

But in reality, dro has some subviews that are not of TOJDropableButtonView class. And one of the subviews of dro happens to be an image view, which has no "type" property, which you are trying to access in your equalToString line.

Make sure your subview of interest is of the class TOJDropableButtonView instead of type casting all subviews to TOJDropableButtonView.

The code below should get rid of your issue.

```
for (UIView *view in dro.subviews) {
    for (UIView *v in view.subviews) {
        if([v isKindOfClass:[TOJDropableButtonView class]]){
            if ([v.type isEqualToString:targetView.filterItem.searchFilterItem.type]){
               NSLog(@"%@", targetView.filterItem.searchFilterItem.type);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hope you understood where/why it was crashing :)